# Problem reading pdf to xml into memory using PDFMiner.Six

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdfminer

Consider the following snippet:

```
import io
result = io.StringIO()
with open("file.pdf") as fp:
    extract_text_to_fp(fp, result, output_type='xml')

data = result.getvalue()
```

This results in the following error

```
ValueError: Codec is required for a binary I/O output
```

If i leave out `output_type` i get the error

```
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 3804: character maps to <undefined>` instead.
```

I don't understand why this happens, and would like help with a workaround.

Comment: I figured out that opening with `mode='rb'` fixes the problem with the variant `output_type='text'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out how to fix the problem:
First you need to open `"file.pdf"` in binary mode. Then, if you want to read to memory, use BytesIO instead of StringIO and decode that.
For example

```
import io
result = io.BytesIO()
with open("file.pdf", 'rb') as fp:
    extract_text_to_fp(fp, result, output_type='xml')

data = result.getvalue().decode("utf-8")
```